# Calling extension function in zend_eval_string

Tags: php, php-extension, php4, php-internals

When i try use zend_eval_string (i make mini php extension), there are no extensions functions avaliable. There are also no errors reporting (if php code have fatal error program exit). 
What i must do to enable extension and show errors when it executes?
I also found interesting value EG(no_extensions)=1; in zend_execute_API.c, but when i change this value to 0 problem not solving. I am newer of c++ and please, tell me how to solve this problem with example.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe help

```
int eval_php_code(char *code) {
    int ret = 0;

    zend_try {
        ret = zend_eval_string(code, NULL, (char *)"" TSRMLS_CC);
    } zend_catch {

    } zend_end_try();

    return ret == FAILURE;
}
```